# Block url wildcards through routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, episerver

I would like to stop all urls with a specific wildcard, example all content files i.e. localhost/content/js, all files under that url should return a 404 page.

I would like to do this programmatically in the routeinitialization.cs meaning I would like to add something similar to this:

```
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute(
            url: "{*contentjsapp}",
            constraints: new { contentjsapp = @"content/js/app/" }
        );
```

But making it show a 404 page instead of ignoring the route as above. However, all examples I find uses a custom 404 controller.

Comment: Perhaps map that route to a controller instead and use that to return the 404 page?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but to quote myself "However, all examples I find uses a custom 404 controller." It's exactly this I'm trying to avoid, and it's the only solution I've found :)

Comment: Well, you could just set the HTTP status code for the response? One way to go would be to use a handler for it (example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097785/how-can-i-return-a-404-error-from-an-asp-net-handler), but I'm note sure why you'd want to do that over a controller? :)

Comment: Or perhaps you could use a location element in web.config and remove all handlers and modules for that path? By the way, why do you want 404:s for those files?

Comment: Would you say the controller is the best way to go? In that case I added this route 
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                "404-PageNotFound",
                "{*url}",
                new { controller = "PageError", action = "PageNotFound" }
            );
And added a controller that does this: return HttpNotFound();
and that works for most things, except if there is a real file on the specified URL, then I get a different error...

Comment: It's for hiding all .js files in a location content/js/app, however it doesn't work with the controller, it still shows all those files. Also for showing a custom 404-page for the views, since if you go to /Views/Home/Index.cshtml it shows an ugly 404 page instead of my custom one.

Comment: Have you configured both customErrors and httpErrors in web.config?

Comment: I added the following customerrors to web.config in Views folder. Now those errors works (show correct 404 page). Thanks! However, how do I block *.js files in a specific folder the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was very simple. Instead of doing it programmatically I could just add the following lines in Web.config (under section :

```
<handlers>
  <add name="BlockContentJsApp" path="/content/js/app/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

And it blocks all wildcards to that page.

Thanks to Ted Nyberg with much help!